# laravel 7 using as uuid foreign key

Tags: laravel, uuid

I have two tables, in both, I am using UUID to generate an id.
after that, I am trying to use one id as a foreign in the second table. as shown
the migration does accept what I am doing but when I insert data I get this error

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'userId' at row 1
```

her is my first tables:

```
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('userName')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->boolean('isVerified')->default(false);
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

the second table with the foreign key

```
Schema::create('tableTwo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('userId');
            $table->foreign('userId')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Can you share the data you try to insert when this error occurs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your are mapping an integer column to uuid column, different types do the sql constraint can't be done ...

you should change:

```
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('userId');
```

to

```
 $table->uuid('userId')->nullable(false);
```

Comment: I did as you said and it accepts inserting data, but still, the two tables are not connected together I can add data to table 2 without having the user in table one! it should say no user with this Id

Comment: have you removed:  $table->foreign('userId')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: you may try: $table->uuid('userId')->nullable(false);

Comment: no i did not remove $table->foreign('userId') ->references('id') ->on('users') ->onDelete('cascade');  why i do need to remove it ?

Comment: I was just making sure of that ... the relation should be builded  right.. did you remigrate your migrations?

Comment: thanks for the response, but I have a question should I add belongs to or has many statements in the model ??

Comment: for User Model: User HasMany of model TableTwo, for TableTwo it belongsTo User Model

Comment: the foreign key is not working not , i now i that has many and belong to thing but the tables are not connected at all

Answer (score 3):

change your code from

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('userId');
```

to

```
$table->foreign('userId')
```

if use laravel 8 you can typing like that

```
$table->foreignUuid('user_id');
```

Comment: i am having the same problem but i already tried everything but still showing the same error, i already try foreignUuid(), foreign(), but still nothing works

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody gets to this question, now laravel allows to use the `foreignUuid` method:

```
$table->foreignUuid('userId')
    ->constrained()
    ->cascadeOnDelete();
```