# Eloquent Uuids as Foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, foreign-keys, uuid

I'm trying to use Uuids as foreign keys in my database. I want the Admin table to reference the User table.

The database is PostgreSQL, but it should work anywway.

The Users' table:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('name', 80);
        $table->string('email', 80)->unique();

        ...

    });
```

My Admins' table:

```
    Schema::create('administrators', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->uuid('fk_user_id');
        $table->foreign('fk_user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        ...

    });
```

I also tried to assign the foreign key as String, since my Uuid trait looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait UsesUuid
{
    protected static function bootUsesUuid()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (! $model->getKey()) {
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string) Str::uuid();
            }
        });
    }

    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }
}
```

So my Admins' table looked like this:

```
    Schema::create('administrators', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fk_user_id', 36);
        $table->foreign('fk_user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        ...

    });
```

I always get the same errors:

```
[2020-10-15 10:52:44] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  foreign key constraint "administrators_fk_user_id_foreign" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "fk_user_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and uuid. (SQL: alter table "administrators" add constraint "administrators_fk_user_id_foreign" foreign key ("fk_user_id") references "users" ("id") on delete cascade) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42804): SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  foreign key constraint \"administrators_fk_user_id_foreign\" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns \"fk_user_id\" and \"id\" are of incompatible types: character varying and uuid. (SQL: alter table \"administrators\" add constraint \"administrators_fk_user_id_foreign\" foreign key (\"fk_user_id\") references \"users\" (\"id\") on delete cascade) at C:\\MyFolder\\Dev\\MyProjects\\Laravel\\VitruvianShield\\vitruvianshield\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:669)
[stacktrace]
```

and

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42804): SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  foreign key constraint \"administrators_fk_user_id_foreign\" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns \"fk_user_id\" and \"id\" are of incompatible types: character varying and uuid. at C:\\MyFolder\\Dev\\MyProjects\\Laravel\\VitruvianShield\\vitruvianshield\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:463)
[stacktrace]
```

How can I do this?
The closest post I found about this was:

[laravel 7 using as uuid foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412258/laravel-7-using-as-uuid-foreign-key)

But somehow it doesn't work.

I'm using Laravel 8, btw.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you using some plugin for the trait `UsesUuid`?

Comment: I used [`goldspecdigital/laravel-eloquent-uuid`](https://github.com/goldspecdigital/laravel-eloquent-uuid) package but with `mysql` and with no issues whatsoever. I not only used for schema generation but also for seeders.

Comment: The package works perfectly @JitendraYadav . Thanks! SHould have used it from the beginning.

Comment: just to make sure, check what is datatype for `uuid` in postgres. Both `string(36)` and `uuid` should have exact datatype

Comment: The error is saying that one column is a uuid type and the other one is a varchar type. Different types can't reference each other

Comment: @apokryfo I know. If you read my full question, you'll see I'm well aware of that. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @JitendraYadav I already checked ;) It's perfect. Thank you once again.

Comment: Actually it's not clear in your question that you are aware of that. You don't mention trying to change `$table->string('fk_user_id', 36)` to `$table->uuid('fk_user_id')` and what happened after that (i.e. what didn't work what sort of error there was). Yes using a library might have solved the issue for you but it may not be an option to other who have the same issue and find this page in hope for solutions

Answer (score 0):

try this here:

````
Schema::create('administrators', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...

        $table->string('fk_user_id');

        ...

    });
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Martin. I did try that. With and without the 36 char limit. My problem was already solved by Jitendra Yadav, though. Thanks anyway.