# How to use foreignUuid in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-migrations, laravel-9

so im trying to use UUID instead of id in my table
i have two tables, in both, I am using UUID to generate an id. after that, I am trying to use one id as a foreign in the second table.

Im using laravel 9

here my first table

[image]

and here is my second table

[image]

but when im trying to run `php artisan migrate` it show this error

[image]

i already trying to find on internet but still got nothing

[laravel 7 using as uuid foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412258/laravel-7-using-as-uuid-foreign-key)
[Foreign key constraint when your primary key is UUID type column](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/foreign-key-constraint-when-your-primary-key-is-uuid-type-column)

thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks, i think i solved it

here's the way, i change my first migration like this
[image: foreignuuid laravel 9]

and my second migration
[image: foreignuuid laravel 9]

Comment: You can actually simplify that a lot:

$table->foreignUuid('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')->index()

(don't forget your indexes ;))